# How to customize chart using chartJs?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, linechart

I'm trying to make a chart like this screenshot.

[image]

Now i'm using `chartjs` as given below:-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>area > boundaries | Chart.js sample</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/style.css">
    <script src="https://www.chartjs.org/dist/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/utils.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/area/analyser.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="wrapper col-2"><canvas id="chart"></canvas></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var presets = window.chartColors;
        var utils = Samples.utils;
        var inputs = {
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            count: 8,
            decimals: 2,
            continuity: 1
        };

        function generateData(config) {
            return utils.numbers(Chart.helpers.merge(inputs, config || {}));
        }

        function generateLabels(config) {
            return utils.months(Chart.helpers.merge({
                count: inputs.count,
                section: 3
            }, config || {}));
        }

        var options = {
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            spanGaps: false,
            elements: {
                line: {
                    tension: 0.000001
                }
            },
            plugins: {
                filler: {
                    propagate: false
                }
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        autoSkip: false,
                        maxRotation: 0
                    }
                }]
            }
        };

        [false,'start'].forEach(function(boundary, index) {

            utils.srand(8);

            new Chart('chart', {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: generateLabels(),
                    datasets: [{
                        backgroundColor: utils.transparentize(presets.red),
                        borderColor: presets.red,
                        data: generateData(),
                        label: 'Dataset',
                        fill: boundary
                    }]
                },
                options: Chart.helpers.merge(options, {
                    title: {
                        text: 'fill: ' + boundary,
                        display: true,
                    }
                })
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

There is issue this is not exactly as screenshot, how can i make it same as in screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *are* using the charts correctly, and you *are* using the appropriate `type: line`. All you have to do to show a chart *exactly* as the image's is set the right values. I hope this gives you an idea

```js
var presets = window.chartColors;
        var utils = Samples.utils;
        var inputs = {
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            count: 8,
            decimals: 2,
            continuity: 1
        };

        function generateData(config) {
            return utils.numbers(Chart.helpers.merge(inputs, config || {}));
        }

        function generateLabels(config) {
            return utils.months(Chart.helpers.merge({
                count: inputs.count,
                section: 3
            }, config || {}));
        }

        var options = {
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            spanGaps: false,
            elements: {
                line: {
                    tension: 0.000001
                }
            },
            plugins: {
                filler: {
                    propagate: false
                }
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        autoSkip: false,
                        maxRotation: 0
                    }
                }]
            }
        };

        [false, 'origin', 'start', 'end'].forEach(function(boundary, index) {
              const canvas = document.getElementById('chart-' + index);
              if(canvas)
              {
               utils.srand(8);
               var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
              new Chart(ctx, {
                  type: 'line',
                  data: {
                      labels: generateLabels(),
                      datasets: [{
                          backgroundColor: utils.transparentize(presets.red),
                          borderColor: presets.red,
                          //data: generateData(),
                          data: [0, 0, 40, 0,0, 50, 0, 0, 0],
                          label: 'Dataset',
                          fill: boundary
                      }]
                  },
                  options: Chart.helpers.merge(options, {
                      title: {
                          text: 'fill: ' + boundary,
                          display: true,
                      }
                  })
              });
            }
        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>area > boundaries | Chart.js sample</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/style.css">
    <script src="https://www.chartjs.org/dist/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/utils.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/area/analyser.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="wrapper col-2"><canvas id="chart-2"></canvas></div>
    </div>

  
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Scaramouche for your efforts.

Comment: how to reduce with of triangle? like given in question screenshot.

Comment: @RohitVerma that depends on the number of values you plot over X, in this case you can go up to 12 since you're using months, the more values you plot over X the thinner the triangles will be

Comment: actually i just need 10-12 with reduce with of triangle as given in top screenshot, it is possible?